# Vim buffer name autocompletion not working after first directory

Tags: vim, gvim, autocomplete, directory-listing

I have a problem with Vim Autocompletion behavior for buffer names.

**Target Soft/OS**

I'm using gVim without plugins on Windows 10

**What I would like to do**

Assuming we have a file tree like :

- a
- b >

  - c
  - d
  - e0
  - e >

    - f
    - g

When I'm searching for a buffer name, here is the behavior I would like :

- `:b <Tab>`   => List "a" "b/" or every files in the cwd, not all buffers names if possible
- `:b b<Tab>`  => `:b b/`
- `:b b/<Tab>` => List "c" "d" "e0" "e/"
- `:b a/e<Tab>` => List "e0" "e/" so I can chose the right path
- `:b a/e/<Tab>` => List "f/" "g/"
  and so on

**What I have tried**

```
set wildmode=longest:list, full
```

If I want to find the file "Core/types.h", and I have the file "Care/file.h" :

- `:b C<Tab>` => it prints every files when I prefer to have only one level of information, like "Core/" and "Care/", not "Core/types.h" and "Care/files.h", but this is the less important issue
- `:b Co<Tab>` => `:b Core/` (This is nice !)
- `:b Core/t<Tab>` => does nothing ! (Why it's not taking "Core/t" as a wildcard ?)
- `:b ty` => `:b Core/types.h`  (This is nice !)

Could it be because of the way I'm opening all my buffers ? I'm doing `gvim **/*` to load all my source files.

**Basically the problem is that the autocompletion doesn't work after a directory, as `:b ty<Tab>` works but not `:b Core/ty<Tab>`**

Hope I was clear and a solution exist for this problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this with Vim 8.0.2 on Windows 8.1.

This seems to be related to the backslashes in the path. If I reconfigure Vim to use forward slashes, completion works as expected:

```
:set shellslash
```

Please report this bug, see `:help bugs`. Basically, open an issue at the [bug tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues), or directly discuss this on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php).

Comment: This is exactly the problem ! Thanks, I'm reporting the bug